# Use the epsilon-delta definition to prove

Tags: real-analysis

Use $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac {\sqrt{4+x}-2} {x} = \frac{1}{4}$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find a $\delta$ such that if $|x-0| < \delta$, $\left|\frac{\sqrt{4+x}-2}{x} - \frac{1}{4}\right| < \epsilon$.
I multiplied by $\frac{\sqrt{4+x}+2}{\sqrt{4+x}+2}$ to rationalize the numerator and combined the fractions to get $\left|\frac{2-\sqrt{4+x}}{4(\sqrt{4+x}+2)}\right|$, but I am not sure where to go from here to relate it to $\delta$.

Comment: This is not epsilon delta, but you can multiply the top and bottom by $\sqrt{4+x}+2$ to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+4}+2}$, which is defined for $x=0$.

Comment: @AnayAggarwal OP does this already.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Right but the continuation was not there

Answer (score 1):

Extended hint:

$\sqrt{4+x}+2$ is continuous and defined at $0$ with output $4$, so for $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary we can find a $\delta > 0$, such that
$$
\lvert x \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert (\sqrt{4+x} + 2) - 4 \rvert = \lvert 2 - \sqrt{4+x}\rvert < \epsilon.
$$
Also
$$
4\leq \lvert 4- \sqrt{4+x}-2\rvert + \lvert \sqrt{4+x}+2 \rvert < \lvert \sqrt{4+x} +2\rvert + \epsilon \implies \frac{1}{4 - \epsilon} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{4+x}+2}.
$$

Finish off from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- The denominator is never smaller than $8$ (for $\ x\ge-4\ $, which must be the case for it to be well-defined).
- And\begin{align} |2-\sqrt{4+x}|<t&\iff 2-t<\sqrt{4+x}<2+t\\
    &\Leftarrow |x| <2t+t^2\ \&\ t<\frac{1}{2}\end{align}